# Send/receive data separately

Tags: c, networking

Say from the server I want to send two strings separately, and on client side I also
want to receive them separately (write to two separate buffers).
Is this the right (only) way to do this?

Sever:

```
char *user1= "nick";
char *user2 = "david";

send(socket, strlen(user1), 4/*assuming int is 4 bytes on sending/receiving machine*/, 0);
send(socket, user1, strlen(user1), 0);

send(socket, strlen(user2), 4, 0);
send(socket, user2 , strlen(user2), 0);
```

Client:

```
  char user1[256],user2[256];
  int x,y;

  // User 1
  recv(socket, &x, 4, 0);
  recv(socket, user1, x, 0);

  // User 2
  recv(socket, &y, 4, 0);
  recv(socket, user2, y, 0);
```

Is this right way to do this? Any explanations/elaborations why this works welcome.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine, **iff** both sending and receiving sides have the same size for `int`, *and* same endianess.

Also note that you might need more than one call to receive the data if you're using TCP sockets.

Comment: thanks I know about multiple calls to receive and possible endianness issues. I was more trying to understand logic behind send and receive calls .. and how to send/receive multiple kind of data simultaneously ... so it seems I more or less got it right? If from server I want to send an **additional** integer to the client after these strings, I just do send `send(socket, &integer, 4, 0);` and on client side also `recv(socket, &integer, 4, 0);` ??

Comment: @dmcr_code For the question in the first comment, yes that's fine. You might want to consider structures though, and as long as you have pretty short strings don't worry about sending the complete arrays. For the second comment, what if two different messages have the same size? For binary protocols (like yours) sending an initial packet type is the most usual.

Comment: Yes, I had similar concern (about same size messages): What if the server wants to send three integers to the client? And client wants to distinguish them, and store in x,y and z. How would you do that?

Comment: @dmcr_code Send and receive the three integers in the same order.